# PHP Cache_Lite Alternative

Tags: php, caching

I'm using Cache_Lite for html and array Cache in my project. I found Cache_Lite may lead to high system IO problem. Maybe because the performance of Cache_Lite is not good

I'm asking is there any stable php html/page cache to use?

I already have APC installed for opcode cache, Memcached installed for common data/array cache.

Comment: just use a a caching HTTP reverse proxy.. php http  proxies make no sense.

Comment: PHP is to slow. You need to cache before the requests even hit PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about https://pear.php.net/package/Cache_Lite then i could tell you a story. We used it once, but it proved to be unreliable for websites with lots of request.

We then switched to  [Zend_Cache](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.cache.html) (ZF1) in combination with memcached. I can be used as standalone component.

However, you have to tune it a bit in order to use tags. There are a few implementations out there to get the job done: https://github.com/bigwhoop/taggable-zend-memcached-backend

Answer (score 2):

I've had exact problem with Cache Lite, as library doesn't properly implement file locks.

Solved it with new library and drop in replacement for Cache Lite.

https://github.com/mpapec/simple-cache/blob/master/example_clite1.php
   https://github.com/mpapec/simple-cache/blob/master/example_clite2.php
   https://github.com/mpapec/simple-cache/blob/master/example_clite3.php

Just to mention that library lacks some features that I didn't found useful like cache cleaning and caching in memory (_memoryCaching property which is false by default and marked as "beta quality" in original library).

Algorithm which is used for file locking follows this diagram,
[image: concurrent read/writes to cache files]

Answer (score 1):

Without more information it is hard to know if you are currently experiencing an IO problem or are likely to experience an IO problem in the future. (If your site is not getting much traffic or you are using a SSD you are unlikely to have a problem)

Cache Lite appears to be a file based caching system. This may lead to IO problems if your site experiences heavy load / lots of concurrent users / is hosted on a shared server / has other programs heavily using the filesystem.

An alternative to Cache Lite is memcache which is a key/value store that stores data in memory. This may not be suitable if you are storing large amounts of data or you server does not have any spare RAM as it stores all of its information in memory. Another benefit of memory is that it is much faster than accessing files from the disk. If you are only accessing a small amount of data or the same data repeatedly this is not likely to be an issue though because of disk/OS caching.

I would suggest checking to see if your system is currently experiencing any issues with IO before worrying about IO performance (unless you plan on getting slashdotted or something)
You could install a tool like Munin http://munin-monitoring.org/ and monitor your system to see if IO is a problem or is becoming a problem. Once installed check the cpu graph and look at the iowait data.

EDIT: Just saw the comment above, depending on your needs reverse proxys are another great tool checkout https://www.varnish-cache.org/ . At work we use a combination of the two ( memcache and varnish) We have 1 machine serving over 900,000 page views per month, this site includes static and dynamic content.